# Tokenizing Data to send into Elasticsearch bulk with standard library Ruby

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I want to use some plain old ruby to send valid data to Elasticsearch so it won't error. Are there guidelines for what I need, code snippets, or standard safe formats I can put my data in so that it won't error when I send it to Elasticsearch?

If there is a library that you want to recommend I may consider it if it has a method that takes a string and outputs something safe I can send to Elasticsearch, but I would like to look at the source and minimize unneeded dependencies. I can make a bare bones version from the source.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the only valid kind of data you send to ES is the one that's JSON. So all you need to take care is, how you create a valid JSON, as that's the only thing ES deals in.

That being said, one of the most common scenario when data gets errored out, is when you define an index mapping/templates yourself while creating the index, and set the data type of all the fields before hand. Now the data you are posting to ES doesn't follow that data type, it will error out while converting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What about single quotes and colons. Do those need to be escaped? Maybe that happens as part of changing things to be valid JSON.

Comment: Correct, those are all part of creating a paresable JSON. If your code builds a good JSON, elastic search would parse it.